# Integers not being copied to array in object

Tags: c++

I have two classes, class point which hold an int x and y value, and class rectangle which holds other values and is a friend of class point. I am trying to take in user input for all of the variable, then transfer the data into an array inside class rectangle.

The x and y values are not being properly transferred to the point variable member in the rectangle class.

I am new to classes and I know it has something to do with how I am accessing the variable in the point class.

```
  //class declarations in header file

   class point {
     int x, y;

public:
    point();
    void setX(point p1, int y);
    void setY(point p1, int y);
    const int getX(point p);
    const int getY(point p);

};
class rectangle{
    int width = 0, length = 0;
    point tlCorner;
    int corners[8]{0};

public:
    const int getWidth(rectangle rec);
    const int getLength(rectangle rec);
    void setWidth(rectangle rec,int w);
    void setLength(rectangle rec,int l);
    void userIn(rectangle &rec);
    void printCoords(rectangle rec);
   rectangle setCorners(rectangle &rec);
   friend class point;
};


//mutator functions for point class
void point ::setX(point p1, int x){
    x = x;
}
void point ::setY(point p1, int y){
   y = y;
}



//user input function that takes in inputs and sets inputs into rectangle 
  object
void rectangle::userIn(rectangle &rec){
    int x, y, width, length;
    cout <<"Enter X coordinate" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    rec.Corner.setX(rec.Corner, x);
    cout <<"Enter Y coordinate" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    rec.Corner.setY(rec.Corner, y);
    cout << "Enter length" << endl;
    cin >> width;
    rec.setLength(rec, length);
    cout << "Enter width" << endl;
    cin >> width;
    rec.setWidth(rec, width);


}
```

My current output is:

```
Enter rectangle 1 values
Enter X coordinate
2
Enter Y coordinate
4
Enter length
2
Enter width
3
Rectangle 1 coordinates
Top left corner: (0,0)
Bottom left corner: (0,-3)
Bottom right corner: (0,-1)
Top right corner: (0,0)
```

Comment: Just on a side note: `const int getWidth();` is not equivalent to `int getWidth() const`. In case you were not aware. Former returns a const value type and the latter is a const member function, meaning you are showing intent that this function will not modify the state of the object. You most likely want the latter, the former doesn't have much use I don' think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void point::setY(point p1, int y){
    y = y;
}
```

should be

```
void point::setY(point p1, int y){
    this->y = y;
}
```

or `y` member or `y` parameter should be renamed.

And `p1` is useless and can be removed.

So simply:

```
void point::setY(int y){
    this->y = y;
}
```

Usage would be similar to:

```
point p;

p.setY(42);
```

Comment: Addendum: Modern compilers are quite smart. Often they will detect and warn you about logical errors like self-assignment. Don't ignore the warnings. Sure, the program compiled and you have a shiny, new program to test out, but the warnings often are hints that the program will not behave as expected and point you at things that you should look at before you waste time testing.

Comment: I created p1 because I thought I needed to specify a point object to set the value. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Xenon8891: free function `void setY(Point& p, int y){/*..*/}` (at namespace scope) or member function `void Point::setY(int y) {/*..*/}`. For setter/getter, member function are more appropriate. for `print`, it might be debatable.